# How to use a single reference cell to change a year reference in a year-month-date across many formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I change the date reference in the formula below: `>=2018-1-01` and `<=2018-1-31`, so that it will refer to a single cell date in cell `J4` correctly?  The formulas below work correctly, no problem!

(E8) `=SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,">=2018-1-01",$B$44:$B$84,"<=2018-1-31")`

(F8) `=SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,">=2018-2-01",$B$44:$B$84,"<=2018-2-28")`

(G8) `=SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,">=2018-3-01",$B$44:$B$84,"<=2018-3-31")`

etc.

The difficulty is that each year I have to manually go in and change every reference to the new year in the formulas, and worse, have to ask people in our volunteer group using the expense report who are not familiar with Excel to go into formulas and edit them. Not very practical on the last part! In cell `J4` if I can just change the date to `2019` next year and have the formulas change, well, everybody will be able to manage that!

Adding a simple cell reference does not work, i.e.:

```
=SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,">=(J4)-1-01",$B$44:$B$84,"<=(J4)-1-31")
```

Other variations similar to just adding `J4` reference in the formula above do not work.

Other variations such as `=(DATE(YEAR(J4),MONTH(1),DAY(1)))` work as a stand-alone reference, but not in the formula. (It often returns `0`.)

The first part of the formula, `=SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,)` is necessary to look up expenses from another table by the month and place them in the monthly columns as per the screen shot. So changing that part of the formula (which works fine) is not an option.

I have tried all kind of date references in the formula and if I don't get an error message, I simply get `0`.

I'm using Excel 2011 (mac)

[image: ScreenShot with Notes and Formulas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

> =SUMIFS(D$44:$D$84,$B$44:$B$84,">="**&J4&**"-1-01",$B$44:$B$84,"<="**&J4&**"-1-31")

Instead of using (J4)

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a#tblID0EABBAFAAA

I have checked that it works fine on my data set, see if this helps you!

[image]

Comment: Side note with **J4** (the year), if your excel needs to be edit each year. It might be beneficial to use this **"=YEAR(TODAY())"** for your J4. So there is no need to ask anybody to change the J4 each year~

Comment: oooh, i was very hopeful!  I hadn't tried that formulation. Unfortunately, I'm getting "0" as a return. I already know that my original formula adds up the numbers and the answer is 72.  (You'd have to have the info in the list to get the same answer.)  Is there a cell formatting setting I'm missing?     On your side note, I thought about that, but when using =Year (Today()) it will automatically return "0" when the new year comes in the columns, as the new year will then be 2019, and the data that is under 2018 will not meet the criteria.

Comment: Can you give me some example row and expected outcome? So I have something more to test on. Other possibility is that, maybe mac 2011 doesn't support the & syntax.

Comment: Sure.  Very kind of you to look.  Perhaps the best thing is to just upload the spreadsheet if you are OK with that.  I'll put some notes in it to help.  Let me see if I can figure out how to upload....

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot with notes and formulas.  Hopefully this gives you something "more" and makes it clearer.  Again, my current formula configuration works fine.  The issue is that I can't put a  correct reference in the formulas for cell J4 (the year) so that changing J4 will change the date reference in all the formulas.  I either get an error message or "0".  (I am unable to upload a spreadsheet, so I made extensive notes on the worksheet and took a screen shot.  Hope that is helpful.)  Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok, screenshot is good enough, I will check it out later.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have checked that, using my Window 2016 Excel version, the formula is working. I suspect either your 2011 version have some problem, or you are not using the correct fomula. An working example Excel & screenshot is attached. Would appreciate if you mark this as acceptable answer if it actually worked this time!

Comment: YES!  Thank you! It works!  There was one key element, however, because at first it did not work.  The FORMAT of the date.  I noticed you had "general" as the format.  I was using a "Date" format.  As soon as I changed it to "general", it worked!!  Thank you!  (I checked the green checkmark, is that correct?)

Comment: Glad it works for you! Yeah the green mark is correct, thank you! BTW I will removed the Excel link now, since no need to keep it here when you already fixed it.